# Jekyll vs RefineryCMS?

Tags: ruby, content-management-system, jekyll, refinerycms

I know many Ruby users are using Jekyll but I wonder what the benefits that will bring over RefineryCMS?

Could someone highlights the differences and pros/cons for each.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm one of the core developers on Refinery CMS.

The architecture of each project is vastly different. Here's a few things Refinery CMS has:

- Web based interface (just go to /refinery to login and edit content)
- Visual content editing (but also supports editing in plain HTML)
- Stores it's content in a database (MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL - your choice)
- Suitable for non technical people to edit
- Supports Rails 3
- Supports localisation in 11 languages (and you can add your own)
- Support and docs: [IRC](http://irc://irc.freenode.net/refinerycms), [Google Group](http://group.refinerycms.org/), [Tutorials](http://tutorials.refinerycms.org/), [API docs](http://api.refinerycms.org/), [Github repository](http://github.com/resolve/refinerycms)

I can't be authoritative about Jekyll (maybe mojombo can answer) but it looks like:

- Static content editing
- Stores it's content in files
- Developer focused, not suitable for an end user to edit
- Markup based editing
- Will load slightly faster as the pages are static

I hope that helps weigh it up. It all comes down to your project requirements.

Answer (score 5):

Well, jekyll is 100% static. All files are generated into static HTML. Jekyll is amazing for small sites that don't really need dynamic content. With jekyll you write the content in your own text editor.

I haven't tested RefineryCMS, but it is more like what you would think of as a content management system with data stored in a database managed through a web interface. If the site is going to be managed by non-tech people, I'll say jekyll is a no-go and that refinery is a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

RefineryCMS is fully Rails 3.0 compatible and they offer great support over IRC. Furthermore RefineryCMS is a fully featured CMS with a localizable interface while Jekyl is not. It all depends on your projects needs.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to install them both and play. You will soon see they both serve two completely different purposes. Refinery is a CMS and Jekyll is a static site generator . Jekyll is not built for content management.